# A-Frame Audio not working in VR-mode only

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm currently working on a small project with a friend of mine. We're playing around with a VR simulation that requires audio instructions. Everything seems to work fine in the web version. The web version also works on mobile devices. However, when you enter VR-mode on any mobile device the audio doesn't play.

We have tried chrome, safari and firefox. None of them seem to work. We have tried different versions of A-Frame but that hasn't worked either. No errors are given, so I have no idea what could be wrong.

This is what we currently have in our index.html:

```
<audio id="js--instructie2" controls>
        <source src="objects/instructie2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
<audio id="js--instructie3" controls>
        <source src="objects/instructie3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
```

as for our main.js:

```
var instructie1 = document.getElementById("js--instructie1");
var instructie2 = document.getElementById("js--instructie2");
var instructie3 = document.getElementById("js--instructie3");
var instructie4 = document.getElementById("js--instructie4");
var instructie5 = document.getElementById("js--instructie5");
var instructie6 = document.getElementById("js--instructie6");

var uitlegArray = [instructie1, instructie2, instructie3, instructie4, instructie5, instructie6];

uitlegArray[uitleg].play();
```

I thought that Audio would work fine in VR-mode given the fact everything works perfectly in the webversion. But appearently it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone having the same issue: Try out the howler plugin. I started trying out different methods and finally solved the issue. I eventually ended up having to use howler.min.js . It's basically an audio library.  Still have no idea how that resolved the issue though, so I'm sorry but I can't provide an answer on why it didn't work to begin with.

You can read more about it on their website:
https://howlerjs.com/